# am attempting to create a searchbox using php. However, when I search code it's not working

Tags: php

```
<div class="row">
                <?php
                $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','product-store');
                if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
                    $searchKey = $_POST['search'];
                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code_no LIKE '%$searchKey%'";


                } else {


                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products order by code_no desc";
                    $searchKey = "";


                }

            ?>
            <form action="tabledata.php" method="POST"> 
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Code" value="<?php echo $searchKey; ?>" > 
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                </div>
                <br>
            </form>

            <br>
            <br>

            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#search").keyup(function() {
          var query = $(this).val();
          if (query != "") {
      $.ajax({
       url:"tabledata.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('#result').html(data);
       }
      });
     }
     $('#searchKey').keyup(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the id in the input field

```
<input type="text" id="search"  name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Code" value="<?php echo $searchKey; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not only missing the id in the input field but you also never execute the query in your php code and fetch the result. And sql injection is possible, sanitize your $searchKey or use prepared statements.

Maybe you can alse place the search query in a differant php file, and create there the html you whant to return to your ajax function.

Maybe this will help:

Create a new php file for your ajax search function like searchData.php

```
    <?php //searchData.php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['query'])) {
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','product-store');

  $searchKey  = $_POST['query']; // Needs to be sanitized to prevent sql injections
  $sql   = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code_no LIKE '%$searchKey%'");

  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    // Fetch the rows
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $html = '';
    // Loop through all the rows
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
      // Create here your html you want to return to your ajax function
    }

    echo $html;

  } else {
    // No results, echo html/ text to the ajax function to inform the user
  }
}
```

Change the url in your ajax function to searchData.php the ajax function will then get all the text/html you echo in this file

Comment: how I can do it please can you explain normal function is working when I need to search any code it's working but I need to show when I type any code its's show dropdown like ajax live search

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example, Your data still needs to be sanitized to prevent sql injections. so do not use this code on a public server

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#search").keyup(function() { 
     var query = $(this).val(); 
     if (query != "") { 
      $.ajax({ 
       url:"searchdata.php", 
       method:"POST", 
       data:{query:query},
        success:function(data) { 
         $('#result').html(data); } 
        }); 
     } 
    $('#search').keyup(function(){ 
     var search = $(this).val(); 
     if(search != '') {
      load_data(search); 
     } else { 
      load_data();
       } 
      }); 
   });
   });
 </script>

Comment: In your ajax function you write the data to an element with id="result" does that exist? also check the network tab when inspecting the page. There you can see the returned result or errors